# When I try to run this program in java it will not work even though there are no errors

Tags: java

When I try to run this program in java it will not work even though there are no errors in eclipse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter how many numbers: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();

        double[] numbers = new double[x];
        double[] orderednumbers = new double[x];

        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
            total += numbers[i];
        }
        double mean = (total / x);
        System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
        orderednumbers[x] = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {

            if (numbers[counter] > orderednumbers[x]) {
                orderednumbers[x] = numbers[counter];
                orderednumbers[x] = orderednumbers[x];
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + orderednumbers[x]);
    }

}
```

Comment: How can you tell it _will not work_?

Comment: not even a stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

This is what's called a runtime error. Sure, it compiles... but for this code you need to be careful with how you handle the array. Your code gave me an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you set `x` early in the code to the length of the array, then go and set `orderednumbers[x]` to 0. This will give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, as since Java array indices are zero-based (i.e. element #1 has index 0, and can be accessed with `orderednumbers[0]`), the length of an array isn't a valid index.

Also, your code for swapping the two numbers in the sort is incorrect; you'll need a temporary variable to store the result. Otherwise, you'll end up making the two places in the array hold the same value.

Try making it this:

```
int temp = orderednumbers[x];
orderednumbers[x] = numbers[counter];
orderednumbers[x] = temp;
```

Note that your statement at the end of the if block:

```
orderednumbers[x] = orderednumbers[x];
```

won't accomplish anything.